# What does it mean by the word "drilled" in the sentence "Exclusive drilled ergonomic reel seat for maximum feedback"?

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence in a [product listing for a fishing pole](https://www.caperlan.co.uk/wixom-9-240-predator-lure-fishing-rod-mh-1030g-id_8401170). Although I get the overall meaning, somehow I am not sure what exactly the word "drilled" means in this sentence:

> ERGONOMIC GRIP
>   Exclusive drilled ergonomic reel seat for maximum feedback.

Comment: What's the context? If this is a product listing what they're talking about is probably clear if they provide a picture.

Comment: here is a link of the product, Laurel https://www.caperlan.co.uk/wixom-9-240-predator-lure-fishing-rod-mh-1030g-id_8401170

Comment: For those of us who don't fish, you might want to define "reel seat" - it appears to refer to the whole handle end including the grip and where the reel actually sits, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *Drill* here has exactly the same meaning as given in the dictionary: "**1** Produce (a hole) in something by or as if by boring with a drill."

Comment: I would change *exclusive* to *exclusively*.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about fishing, but a bit more about manufacturing, and can only read that as *with one or more holes drilled in it*. This is probably in comparison to alternative products which either:

- have holes moulded in to them (more friction, and/or less even friction on rotating parts, as the holes will be less straight and less round)
- are solid, and therefore heavier and stiffer
- (if referring to a tube) have thicker walls. Here, drilling one end is again a way of adjusting stiffness and weight.

I suspect in this case the third point applies - the handle end is thicker than the rest of the pole and without drilling would be both heavy and stiff (assuming the carbon fibre layup wasn't too clever).